# Which load testing method is better? API testing or full website testing

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I have an application that we implemented kind of a microservices type architecture. The application contains 6 services (6 Docker containers). I need to load test this application. As I don't have much experience in the testing field, I'm not sure which method to use.

Right now, I have used the Gatling Load testing application for the load test. Here, I record the testing script by start the recorder and wander around my application to record all routes. I have gone through most of the routes in that single recording in order to mimic a practical user. I thought, normally users use an application like this and I can load test with its 1000 times by editing the number of threads/users.

Later I read about API testing which we will focus on APIs. Loading each APIs with a heavy load. So, I'm confused that which testing method should I use? If we go for API testing, it will provide only how much we can scale for that particular API right? (Not sure)

Is there any issue with my method of load testing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on what you hope to achieve...

If you're looking to validate that your entire application (code + production infrastructure) can handle a given load, then driving as though going through the full website is the right path.

However, if you're looking to see how a particular api scales or want to help developers explore the ramifications of changes, then you will probably want to just drive that API directly to avoid other limitations your system may have.